# Why is QR Code not written as ZPL command

Tags: qr-code, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I'm using the ZebraDesigner software to create a simple label with a QR Code. It looks good when I print it, but I also need the .prn file with all the information contained inside the QR Code to be "readable". When I open the .prn file with Notepad++, the QR Code line looks like this:

```
,:::::::::::::::::M07FHFI01FHFC00FFC1FMFC,::::M07C1F07C1FF80H0F801F0K07C,::::O01FKFH03FF0H01F07FHF07C,::::M07FE0F83E007FIF801F07FHF07C,::::M07FHF07FHFH03E0FFC1F07FHF07C,::::M07C00F83E007FIF801F0K07C,::::O01FF80H0HFC1FHFC1FMFC,::::M07C1F0H01FHFC1F07C,::::O01FF801FHFC1F0H01FF83FIFC,::::R07C1FF801FHFC0J01FHFC,::::M07FE0FJFH03E0I01F003E,::::M07C1FF83E007FE0F80I07FE0FFC,::::M07C00FKF83FF07FHF07C0H07C,::::W07FE0FFC,::::M07FMF07C1F07C1FMFC,::::M07C0J01F003FF07C1F0K07C,::::M07C1FHFC1F07C0H07C1F07FHF07C,::::M07C1FHFC1F07FE0FFC1F07FHF07C,::::M07C1FHFC1F0J0F801F07FHF07C,::::M07C0J01F07C0J01F0K07C,::::M07FMF07C0H07C1FMFC,::::,::::^XA
```

But i want it to be in pure ZPL, just like this one, shown in the [The Zebra Programming Guide](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/en-us/software/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) 
:

```
^FO20,20^BQ,2,10^FDQA,0123456789ABCD
```

Does anyone know what should I do to generate the file like the one in the documentation or how can I convert it? I've already done a lot of research, but I can't sort it out.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this. I reinstalled the printer via ZebraDesigner and changed its port from LPT to USB. Now the .prn file is finally being generated correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to reproduce the problem by using a micro QR code.

If that's not mandatory, I suggest you use a "standard" QR code.

Comment: I'm actually using the standard QR Code, not the micro.

Comment: How do you generate it via the interface ?

Comment: I'm using the Zebra Designer software (can be downloaded [here](https://www.zebra.com/us/en/products/software/barcode-printers/zebralink/zebra-designer.html)). The "QR" object, which is the one I use, is inside the "2D" category of the toolbox.

Answer (score 0):

It happens when you use different **fonts** on your label design. If you use Windows fonts, The ZebraDesigner will convert the text into a graphic.

So use Zebra fonts.